# Is it correct to say 'две штуки' or 'два штуки' when talking about something masculine?

Tags: числительные, род

For example 'два пельменя', where 'пельменя' is masculine, so when referring to them, should it be 'два штуки'?

Answer (score 8):

Definitely `две` because `штуки` is feminine.
As for `пельмень`, it's masculine, so the correct form is `два пельменя`.

Comment: Yes, is it still that still 'две' if 'штуки' is used when talking about 'пельменя'? Just making sure

Comment: @user20821 Undoubtedly.

Comment: @user20821 Yes, "два пельменя" is a no-brainer. You would be in a much stickier situation, though, if it was not "пельмени" but "манты". The "штуки" would come in really handy then. "Дайте мне манты, две штуки". 